# How do I check to see if a message collector collected an image? And how do I get that image's Discord URL/proxyURL?

Tags: discord.js

I'm coding in Discord.js V12 and I want to know how to fetch the attachments of a collected message in an awaitMessages() message collector.

The output of a `collected` (a collected message with only an image in it) is this:

```
Collection [Map] {
  '701180292689297429' => Message {
    channel: DMChannel {
      type: 'dm',
      deleted: false,
      id: '700086368558121047',
      recipient: [User],
      lastMessageID: '701180292689297429',
      lastPinTimestamp: null,
      messages: [MessageManager],
      _typing: Map {}
    },
    deleted: false,
    id: '701180292689297429',
    type: 'DEFAULT',
    content: '',
    author: User {
      id: '252268366079852584',
      bot: false,
      username: 'EBB',
      discriminator: '5732',
      avatar: 'd60958dccad619bd70225373ed312bbf',
      flags: [UserFlags],
      lastMessageID: '701180292689297429',
      lastMessageChannelID: '700086368558121047'
    },
    pinned: false,
    tts: false,
    nonce: undefined,
    system: false,
    embeds: [],
    attachments: Collection [Map] { '701180291405971506' => [MessageAttachment] },
    createdTimestamp: 1587244809077,
    editedTimestamp: null,
    reactions: ReactionManager {
      cacheType: [Function: Collection],
      cache: Collection [Map] {},
      message: [Circular]
    },
    mentions: MessageMentions {
      everyone: false,
      users: Collection [Map] {},
      roles: Collection [Map] {},
      _members: null,
      _channels: null,
      crosspostedChannels: Collection [Map] {}
    },
    webhookID: null,
    application: null,
    activity: null,
    _edits: [],
    flags: MessageFlags { bitfield: 0 },
    reference: null
  }
}
```

This is the code I'm referring to:

```
dmc.awaitMessages(resp => resp.author.id === message.author.id, {
                max: 1,
                time: 60000,
                errors: ['time']
              }) 
              .then(collectedfive => {
                    let imageOrNo = collectedfive.first().content
                    console.log(imageOrNo)
                    message.channel.send(<I WOULD SEND THE IMAGE BACK TO THEM, BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW TO, AND I ALSO WOULD CHECK TO SEE IF THERE IS AN ATTACHED IMAGE TO THE MESSAGE)
                  })
})
```

I want to get the attachments and their URLs (the `proxyURL`s, specifically) and also check if a collected message has any attachments at all using Discord.js V12. How would I go about doing so?

Comment: Could you post the output of console.logging your collected message in your question? and can you add some of your code?

Comment: @Syntle Alright, done.

Comment: Could you show the code snippet the question is about?

Comment: @Syntle Sorry for the hassle, lol. I've added some of the code I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You'd simply have to check if the message has attachments, then get the message's attachments and loop through them and send them to the channel.

```js
dmc.awaitMessages(resp => resp.author.id === message.author.id, {
    max: 1,
    time: 60000,
    errors: ['time']
})
.then(collectedfive => {
        if (collectedfive.first().attachments.array().length) {
            collectedfive.first().attachments.forEach((attachment) => {
                message.channel.send({ files: [attachment] })
            })
        }
    })
```

You can also get the `proxyURL` property of the attachments by using `attachment.proxyURL` in the `forEach()` loop above